# Rails 4 app with has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, associations, nested-attributes, has-many-through

I need to make an application in which there are two models: User and Company. In this case, users may be employees of the company, and then the user must be associated with Company model, and if the user is not an employee of the company, the connection with the Company model should not be.

I'm trying to make it through the association has_many through:

Models:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: companies
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  name       :string
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :company_users
  has_many :users, through: :company_users
end

# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id              :integer          not null, primary key
#  first_name      :string
#  last_name       :string
#  email           :string
#  created_at      :datetime         not null
#  updated_at      :datetime         not null
#

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :company_users
  has_many :companies, through: :company_users
end

# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: company_users
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  company_id :integer
#  user_id    :integer
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#

class CompanyUser < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Companies controller

```
class CompaniesController < ApplicationController

  def signup
    @company = Company.new
    @user = @company.users.build
  end

  def create
    @company = Company.new(company_params)
    @company.save
  end

  private

  def company_params
    params.require(:company).permit(:name, users_attributes: [:first_name, :last_name, :email])
  end
end
```

signup.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@company) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>         
  <%= f.fields_for(@user) do |user_f| %>
    <%= user_f.text_field :first_name %>
    <%= user_f.text_field :last_name %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

But it does not work. Saved only instance of the model of the Company.
How to association must be made in the models, and as should be done in the controller action Companies in creating a company with an employee?

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is some extra information specific to the relationship between Company and User, I would use the has_and_belongs_to_many relationship instead and have one less model in your app.

In this case your classes would look like:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :companies
end
```

The second line in Company is what you were missing, and it tells Rails to look out for `users_attributes`.

For more details on nested attributes:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

If you want to keep the relationship model, then I believe you will need to nest your nested attributes, e.g.

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :company_users
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :company_users
end

class CompanyUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :user

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :company_users
end
```

Your form data will then need to look like:

`company[company_users][][user][first_name]=First`

Comment: Yes, but I need to work with the relationship model as an independent entity.

Comment: In that case I believe you will need to nest your nested attributes.  I updated my answer with an example